# Dimension Member as Calculated Measure in MDX

Tags: sql-server, olap, mdx

I need to get a dimension member returned as a calculated measure.

Given:

Dimensions

- Customer {ACME, EMCA, Universal Imports, Universal Exports}
- Salesperson {Bob, Fred, Mary, Joe}
- Credit Type {Director, Manager}

Measures

- Credited Value
- Value

Relationships

- The Customer is a dimension of the facts that contain Value
- The Customer, Salesperson and Credit Type are dimensions of the facts that contain Credited Value

I am trying to do the following:

Create calculated measures that will return the Salesperson with the largest $s credited in a role for a customer. e.g.

```
| Customer          | Director | Manager | Value |
|-------------------|----------|---------|-------|
| ACME              | Bob      | Fred    | 500   |
| EMCA              | Bob      | Fred    | 540   |
| Universal Imports | Mary     | Joe     | 1000  |
| Universal Exports | Mary     | Fred    | 33    |
```

- ACME has Bob credited with 490 as Director
- ACME has Fred credited with 500 as Manager
- ACME has Mary credited with 10 as Director

I would like to use this as a calculated measure that I can use in any case where Customers are the ROW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, something along this line should do the trick (of course you'd have to use the proper level, hierarchy and cube names):

```
   with
    member [Measures].[DirectorTemp] as topcount([Salesperson].[Salesperson].members,1,([Measures].[Credited Value],[Credit Type].[Director],[Customer].currentmember)).item(0).properties("Caption")   
    member [Measures].[Director] as iif([Measures].[DirectorTemp] = [Salesperson].UnknownMember.properties("caption"), null, [Measures].[DirectorTemp])
    member [Measures].[ManagerTemp] as topcount([Salesperson].[Salesperson].members,1,([Measures].[Credited Value],[Credit Type].[Manager],[Customer].currentmember)).item(0).properties("Caption") 
    member [Measures].[Manager] as iif([Measures].[ManagerTemp] = [Salesperson].UnknownMember.properties("caption"), null, [Measures].[ManagerTemp])


    select
        {[Measures].[Director],[Measures].[Manager],[Measures].[Value]} on 0,
        {[Customer].members} on 1
    from MyCube
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have adapted it to my data.
One quick question.  If the Tuple returns a set of none, I get the Unknown member from the Salesperson dimension.  How can I avoid this?

Comment: I've edited the query so it returns null instead of "Unknown". A bit messier, but it should work...

Comment: Thanks.  I have tackled slightly different.  I wrapped a iff(isempty(**Tuple Definition**), NULL, TOPCOUNT .... As previously specified) to accomplish a similar result. 

My only problem know is with CurrentMember not working properly when  two hierarchies from the Customer Dimension are in the select statement and the results are filtered.